# Laravel 5: Blank Item for select method in FormBuild

Tags: php, laravel-5, formbuilder

Is there some way to insert a blank option when creating a select input with the Laravel FormBuilder? I have this at the moment but I want to change it

```
{!! Form::select('tipo_id', ['blank' => ''] + $tipos, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do too much better than you are already doing. Secret is to have array first element empty to show blank input.